# Syncfusion Integration platform: how to import custom processor?

Tags: integration, etl, apache-nifi, syncfusion, bigdata

I trying to import my custom processor in **Syncfusion Integration platform**.

Since Syncfusion integration is based on Apache NiFi, I try to put compiled processor (i.e **.nar** file) to lib directory:

```
/syncfusion_location/SDK/NIFI/lib
```

Then restart Syncfusion.
But I can't find my processor in processors list.

When I do this in pure NiFi import works fine (also that way is described in NiFi docs).

What I'm doing wrong with Syncfusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they doing Check "custom" word in processor type.

If that word present in that type then UI show your processor.

**For example:**

If your processor type like below.

```
org.apache.nifi.processors.MyProcessor.Type
```

then it doesn't show in your UI.

If you change that like this.

```
org.apache.nifi.processors.custom.MyProcessor.Type
```

then it will show your processor in UI.

Let me know if you face any issues

Comment: Odd, but it works!
I changed the package by add "custom" word
and I updated org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor file accordingly to new package name.

Comment: This may be a restriction that Syncfusion has added but it is not a requirement of Apache NiFi.